# Show that $f=0$ a.e. if $|\int_I f|^p \leq c|I|^{p-1}\int_I |f|^p$ with $0<c<1$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> Suppose an extented real valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the following two properties:
>
> a) There is a $p$, $1\leq p < \infty$ such that $f\in L^p(I)$, for every bounded interval $I\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and
>
> b) $|\int_I f|^p\leq c|I|^{p-1} \int_I |f|^p$ for every bounded interval $I\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a constant $0<c<1$ independent of $I$.
>
> Show that $f=0$ a.e.

My Work:

We must prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f|=0$. By Holder's inequality, $|\int_I f|\leq \int_I |f|=\int_I |f\chi_I|\leq (\int_I |f|^p)^\frac{1}{p}(\int_I |\chi_I|^\frac{p}{p-1})^\frac{p-1}{p}$. Hence $|\int_I f|^p\leq |I|^{p-1} \int_I |f|^p$. Since then I was stuck. What else I can do here to proceed? Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by an interval $I\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: A cell in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you mean a subset of the form $[a_1,b_1]\times\ldots\times[a_n,b_n]$?

Comment: @Jason your one is only a special case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose (a) holds and that it is not the case that $f$ is $0$ a.e..  Let $x$ be a Lebesgue point of $f$ and of $|f|^p$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.  Then

$$|f(x)|^p=\left|\lim\limits_{I\to x}\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I f\right|^p$$

and

$$|f(x)|^p=\lim\limits_{I\to x}\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I |f|^p,$$

so

$$\lim\limits_{I\to x}\left|\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I f\right|^p=\lim\limits_{I\to x}\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I |f|^p,$$

and recall these are nonzero limits.  Thus given $c$ with $0<c<1$, there exists $I$ sufficiently small centered at $x$ such that $\left|\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I f\right|^p>c\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I |f|^p$.  Therefore (b) does not hold.

Comment: What do you mean by a Lebesgue point?

Comment: @Mathi: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem.  In brief, it means a point that makes the following limit statements true, and the fact that such $x$ exists follows from a theorem I am invoking to do all of the work.

Comment: Really I don't understand this solution. Can I get a contradiction by the same way if I assume that $f\neq 0$ on a set of non zero measure?

Comment: Really Mathi that's fine.   Sure you can get a contradiction, or you could use contraposition as I did, but saying you will use contradiction doesn't really indicate the method you're going for. If you have specific questions about this answer, you may ask and I might try to help clarify.

Comment: Got it! I have forgotten the definition of a Lebesgue set and all related theorems